# Gulp SASS 1 line results in error

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have this line of SCSS:

```
height: calc(#{$drawer-padding} + #{$drawer-profile-img} + #{$drawer-profile-content-height} + #{$drawer-profile-bottom-padding});
```

Everytime I try to run Gulp, it will return the following error:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

I get this error using gulp-sass. The error is only caused by that line and everything worked just fine before that.

I hope someone can help me with the error.

**Update**

When I delete the last part `+ #{$drawer-profile-bottom-padding}` it does work. It looks like as if there are too many `#{}`.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled across exactly the same issue. It looks like a stack overflow.
In my case it is reproducible only under Windows environment. Any Linux distributive I've tried deals with it well.

As a workaround for Windows (since apparently it allows only 1MB of stack tops) I've lifted up a bit maximum stack size limitation using `editbin` which is a part of [C/C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools).

`editbin /STACK:2097152[,commit] node.exe`

You may also try using `--stack-size` option for node.